# Why isn't apache2 redirecting to https, or acting how I expect with mediawiki?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki site on Ubuntu 14.04, that is working perfectly, and is housed at `/var/www/html`

I'm trying to get https setup on the server, and I haven't been able to get that done yet.  Here's my current port 80 configs, and I'll show what I'm trying below that.

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywiki.com
    ServerAlias http://mywiki.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/www/html/LocalSettings.php**

```
#this is the only relevant line...I think.
$wgServer = "http://mywiki.com"
```

---

The changes I'm making, in order, are below

**1.**  Change `$wgServer` value to `//mywiki.com`

**2.**  Edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` to the following

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerName mywiki.com
    Redirect permanent / https://mywiki.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName mywiki.com
    ServerAlias https://mywiki.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**3.**  Stop apache from using the old `000-default.conf` file by running `sudo a2dissite 000-default`.

**4.**  Start using the new ssl default file by running `sudo a2ensite default-ssl`.

**5.**  Restart Apache2 `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

At this point, apache2 restarts correctly, and there are no errors from the output or in the error.log.  However, when I go to the site by typing `mywiki.com` it doesn't redirect me to `https`, and now it shows the `:80` section of the site as the `Index of / html/`.

When I try to manually go to `https://mywiki.com`, I get a page not available, like it's not even trying.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a silly solution, but I imagine on a product like mediawiki, I won't be the last to make this mistake.

I never enabled the ssl module

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
```

I went through tens of tutorials on how to setup ssl on mediawiki, and none of them mentioned this.  It's pretty obvious if you work on lots of websites, but I don't, and hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a ServerName. This might be it. Could you attempt this configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywiki.com
    Redirect permanent / https://mywiki.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerName mywiki.com
    ServerAlias www.mywiki.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/my.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that to the files, and it doesn't appear to have changed anything.  I was definitely missing it though.

Comment: Alright. I have used this configuration many times so it's weird that it does not work. Do not be offended by this question, but did you restart the apache service after adding these lines?

Comment: I don't find that offensive at all, I bet that's the #1 fix for these problems.  I did restart.  I also restarted the machine for good measure.

Comment: Alright, I just looked somethings up. First of all. The `NameVirtualHost *:80` is redundant and will be removed in the next release. Secondly I just attempted this configuration on my machine and it works fine for some reason (without he NameVirtualHost). I did specify the SSL virtual host using `<VirtualHost *:443>` instead of with `_default_`.

Comment: I tried removing the ```_default``` and that did nothing.  Also, because it's not even redirecting, I think there's a configuration issue that's causing it to not use the correct ssl file.  I'm not sure at this point.  Also, I didn't use NameVirtualHost anywhere.